# Which linker is used by gcc?

Tags: gcc, linker

How to determine which linker is used by my gcc?
For example I have 3 linkers:
2 in one directory, same place as for gcc
and another one linker in another directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may add `-Wl,-verbose` to your `gcc` link command or use

```
gcc -print-prog-name=ld
```

Comment: Do you know, can I select linker with some gcc option?

Comment: Yes, the `-B` option sets the binary search path. But beware, the above command tells you where the `ld` binary is. It doesn't tell you if your GCC is configured to use something else, such as `ld.gold`, although it probably isn't.

Comment: Oh, and if `-print-prog-name=ld` returns just `ld` then that means GCC is just using whatever `ld` is on the ordinary `$PATH`.